# PDO with $_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, pdo

I have a little problem,

For exemple, the last time i used MySQL and now PDO, so that was my problem:

When a user want post a message on my website, with MySQL, if he try to post something like `<div class="HAHAHA">` it doesn't work or it gonna show: `From USER, Message => <div class="HAHAHA">`

But now with PDO, when users post like HTML that gonna work on my website. (I don't know if that make a sence).

My piece of code:

```
<?php $contenu = nl2br($_POST['contenu']);

$sql_add_pub = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO publications (steamid,profile,contenu,ajout,ip) VALUES ('".$user['steamid']."','".$user['steamid']."', :contenu , '".time()."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."') ");
        $sql_add_pub->execute(Array("contenu" => $contenu)); ?>
```

So my question is, how can i fix that with PDO ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For a start never use user input in your query string. Use Prepared Statements. That will help prevent SQL injection.

Secondly use the PHP strip_tags function on user input. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

This will stop people from injecting HTML.

Comment: Thank you so mutch, that exactly what i need and that work perfectly now.
I'm gonna use Prepared statements for user like you told me :)

Comment: Do not use `strip_tags` arbitrarily. The prepared statement will take care of injecting. `htmlspecialchars()` needs to be used when displaying content to avoid XSS issues.

Comment: What do you mean by do not use strip_tags arbitrarily? It's certainly not the only thing you should do. It is one of many things that can improve sanitisation of user input.